# "Not so much as...but..." or "not so much as...but as...?"

Tags: not-so-much-as

What's more grammatically correct?

> I knew she would be standing here, waiting for me. **No, not so
>   much as waiting but *expecting me to be here.**

or

> I knew she would be standing here, waiting for me. **No, not so
>   much as waiting but as expecting me to be here.**

Comment: (3) No, not so much waiting as expecting me to be here. cf: One might almost suppose that he was not so much reinventing his past as confirming his present, projecting his current degree of success backward in time, ...// He overlapped Shane Warne, but says he was not so much overawed by him as misled // He was not so much a politician as an institution.[Google: "he was not so much"](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=en&q=%22he+was+not+so+much%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first structure is correct.

> I knew she would be standing here, waiting for me. No, not so much as waiting **but expecting** me to be here.

No need for *as* in the second part. The first instance of *as* used is a part of the idiomatic expression *not so much as* itself and not a prefactory to *waiting*.

The more common idiom however, is to place the *as* in the second part without *but* to convey exactly the same meaning.

[**not so much *sth* as *sth***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/not-so-much-sth-as-sth)

> I knew she would be standing here, waiting for me. No, not so much <strike>as</strike> waiting <strike>but</strike> **as expecting** me to be here.

Comment: I find the first structure to be almost impossible to parse. As you say, the idiom is "not so much A as B," so leaving out the second "as" creates both idiomatic and syntactic issues. Perhaps removing the first "as" would help, but not much.

Answer (score 1):

Neither rendition in the example is the best. Proper English idioms suggest the use of "not so much ... as ..."  Example:

> I knew she would be standing here, waiting for me. No, not so much waiting, as expecting me to be here.